# how to find keywords in a pdf document and highlight them using JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat

Tags: javascript

**How do I find keywords in a pdf document and highlight them using JavaScript in Adobe Acrobat?**

I've tried using arrays, where list of arrays contains the keywords that needs to be filtered in the document I opened in adobe acrobat, but unable to find and highlight them using JavaScript.

The below code is finding for one keyword which has to enter every time with new keywords in the if condition and run.

```js
var keywords = ["ex1", "ex2", "ex3", "ex4", "ex5"];

if (keywords.indexOf("ex1") !== -1) {
  alert("Yes, the value exists!");
} else {
  alert("No, the value is absent.");
}
```

But what I need is to run code single time, picking keywords in that runtime and highlight all the keywords exists in the document.

Comment: code is in the description sir

Comment: Consider using the LEADTOOLS JavaScript Document Viewer SDK (Disclaimer: I work for the vendor) which can use a [DocumentViewerText.find](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/javascript/doxui/documentviewertext-find.html) method to asynchronously locate the keywords and let them be highlighted. You can find an example of this in the [online demo](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/index.html) where a searched term will be highlighted throughout the document. The source code for this viewer can be found in the free evaluation download, should you wish to try it.